# How do you resize Vmware disk image?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I am using VMWARE ESXi3.5 Version. I created a 40GB partition which I want to decrease this to 25GB. How to do this?

Regards,
Hari K Prasad.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way of accomplishing this on v3.5 is to run the VM through the VMWare Converter software again, this time picking a smaller disk size.

You'll have to have enough space to hold both the original VM and new VM while the conversion completes, but once the new VM has booted successfully, you can remove the old copy.

Answer (score 2):

I'll second Chris' method. In fact, I just used it to resize a VM that holds an old laptop image.

However, for completeness sake, I did find the following resource pretty useful where the author lists 6 different ways to resize.

http://vsphere-land.com/tips-tricks/re-sizing-virtual-disks